# Python OOP: Are all self."something" attributes in __init__ available to other class methods?

Tags: python, oop

Simple, silly question.
But say I had

```
class Stuff:

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name:

    def get_name(self):

        print(name)

new_name = Stuff(name = "Richard")
new_name.get_name()
```

Would this work? Would get_name be able to access the name attribute and print it out?

I can't get this code to work...

Comment: I suggest that the getter `get_name` return the name rather than print it. The caller can print the name later if it chooses so.

Comment: You could just access `new_name.name`. No true need for a getter

Comment: `self.name` works because `self` represents the instance of a class. So that instance has its own attributes that can be accessed across all methods using `self.*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to change but this works:

```
class Stuff:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.name)

new_name = Stuff(name = "Richard")
new_name.get_name()
```

Besides a few syntax errors (`class` needs to be lowercase and some missing `:`) the main thing you were missing was accessing `name` by means of the `self` identifier. Since `name` is defined on the class you need to access it via `self`.

Comment: It's the "self" in the print. You cleared it up! Thanks!

Comment: So, my guess is that anything within the class will be called self.functionname?
Kind of like "this" in PHP....

Comment: @orchd Exactly. However, you can even rename `self` to `this ` to help ease the transition

Comment: also, since the name of the function is `get_name`, it is supposed to return the `self.name`, and not print it